# In App Purchase DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF case

Tags: php, ios, swift, in-app-purchase

As mentioned in apple docs:
We are implementing In-App Purchase and using **Subscription Status Update notifications** (subscription status URL) to update our DB with the subscription status

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

**DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF** : Customer changed the plan that takes affect at the next subscription renewal. The current active plan is not affected.

Do all the plans changed from iTunes have this notification. If not then when do we get the above case.

***How do we maintain a track of the which is the user's current subscription on the app's backend?***

Comment: I had faced the same issue, didn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

**How do we maintain a track of the which is the user's current subscription on the app's backend?**

You have to perform receipt validation by sending existing receipt to iTunes Server and in return you will get updated receipt. You can check current subscription for particular product id from that receipt.

Comment: So when the next renewal is done. Do we get a status update notification from apple?

Comment: You will not get notification at that time but you have to perform receipt validation periodically. You will get only once you changes it from iTunes.